# Elasticsearch: Generating an aggregate field during search query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, aggregation

new to ES here. I'm trying to implement a search engine from a source with the following schema in 1 index:

```
index:paper
{
"title": string,
"author": string,
"id": string,
"references": [string:another_paper.id, string:another_paper.id, ...],
"pubDate": date
}
```

Let's say I want to perform a search for all papers with the author "A. Smith" between the dates 2017-01-09 to 2017-01-30.

How would I craft my search query to get results with a generated field that says how many times each document is referenced by other documents under the "references" field? Is this even possible in ES?

Execution speed is not important and I can tolerate relatively slow execution speed, but I do not want to update existing documents when I upload new documents.

Thank you

Comment: Please, use code styling for pieces of code you have in your question

Comment: Added code styling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get results based on author name and date range.
With this query you can get the number of documents that have been referenced by the documents matching to the query and the count tof the documents.

In short you can get number of referenced documents based on other documents

For eg lets say you index 3 documents

```
{
  "title": "title1",
  "author": "bob",
  "id": "id1",
  "references": [
    "id1",
    "id2",
    "id3"
  ],
  "pubDate": "01-01-2018"
},
{
  "title": "title2",
  "author": "harry",
  "id": "id2",
  "references": [
    "id1",
    "id3",
    "id7",
    "id8"
  ],
  "pubDate": "01-02-2018"
},
{
  "title": "title3",
  "author": "bob",
  "id": "id3",
  "references": [
    "id1",
    "id4",
    "id7",
    "id9"
  ],
  "pubDate": "01-03-2018"
}
```

After this you can fire a query

```
GET test_stackoverflow_agg/type1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "author:bob AND pubDate:[2018-01-02 TO 2018-01-04]"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "references",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query part will tell you which documents to filter and

the aggregation part will tell you on which field you want to get count of the unique ids present in reference field

Here is how results of this look like

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.0460204,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_stackoverflow_agg",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "id3",
        "_score": 1.0460204,
        "_source": {
          "title": "title3",
          "author": "bob",
          "id": "id3",
          "references": [
            "id1",
            "id4",
            "id7",
            "id9"
          ],
          "pubDate": "2018-01-03"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_stackoverflow_agg",
        "_type": "type1",
        "_id": "id1",
        "_score": 1.0460204,
        "_source": {
          "title": "title1",
          "author": "bob",
          "id": "id1",
          "references": [
            "id1",
            "id2",
            "id3"
          ],
          "pubDate": "2018-01-02"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "agg1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "id1",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "id2",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "id3",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "id4",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "id7",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "id9",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```